# New install of VS 2015 won't compile anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008

I have been using VS 2008, and have installed VS 2015 side by side on the same computer. I have projects compiled in VS 20015 from another computer that compile just fine. But when I open those projects and try to compile them in the new VS 2015 on this computer they will not compile. In fact, even creating the simplest "Hello world" application will not compile.

I get errors on standard VS header files. For example, it throws errors and warnings on Windows.h like:

> Warning   C4067   unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive -
>   expected a newline    windows.h
>
> Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'LPCSTR'
>    Error  C2061   syntax
>   error: identifier 'BYTE'

I can't figure out why this is happening. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: probably you just have stray character on the line where you include windows.h

Comment: No that's not it. Like I said, the exact same project and source code compiles just fine on another computer with VS 2015. And creating just a simple "blank" project throws the same errors.